# How can I allow an empty string value for optional enum with NestJs?

Tags: nestjs

I am successfully validating my dto for valid enum types:

```
// time-unit.enum.ts

export enum TimeUnit {
  SECONDS = 'SECONDS',
  MINUTES = 'MINUTES',
  HOURS = 'HOURS',
  DAYS = 'DAYS',
}
```

```
// create-thing.dto.ts

@ApiPropertyOptional({
    description: 'The lead time unit.',
    example: 'DAYS',
  })
  @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(TimeUnit)
  unit?: TimeUnit;
```

On the front-end, I am providing a `<select>` that is populated with an empty string for default value, then the corresponding enum values.

If I choose a value, everything works great! This is an optional field (a nullable column). So If I attempt to save without choosing something, I'll get a 400 error:

> leadTime.unit must be a valid enum value

How can I allow an empty string as a valid enum option?

Comment: This thread has a couple of workarounds: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/326

Comment: An empty string is still a value. So, your best bet is to either don't pass the param at all or convert the empty string to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to transform the the value if its equal to empty string
// create-thing.dto.ts

```js
@ApiPropertyOptional({
    description: 'The lead time unit.',
    example: 'DAYS',
  })
  @Transform((params) => (params.value === '' ? null : params.value))
  @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(TimeUnit)
  unit?: TimeUnit;
```

Comment: Finally getting back to this. Thank you so much for your suggestion! Based on your suggestion, I found that also checking for empty string/convert to `null` in my front-end application works well too.

Comment: what about if we use @Param decorator in controller without using dtos. How can we transform value to null if it is empty string?